# Database design - configuration/settings table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

The application has multiple notifications push, email, sms etc

Push has 4-5 settings, email has the same as push+ more settings

- Should I keep all the notification settings in 1 table or 3 tables?
- Or one table for each notification type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that I like working with a single table for this sort of scenario. Its especially useful when you have some common base fields that all the types will share. ORM frameworks such as the Entity Framework will allow you to split a single table into multiple entities and define the inheritance relationships.

Comment: At this level of simplicity I wouldn't normalize either.

Answer (score 0):

Although somewhat arbitrary I typically find that sort of data stored in one table with a category column to identify what type of setting it is. Especially since the data can all be categorized as notification data.

The only argument I see in favor of 3 separate tables is that it might be slightly easier to use with an ORM.